# React.js 18 double effect on mount makes difficult to implement page-in and page-leave logic

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Consider this example:

```js
const { useEffect } = React;

const items = [];

const addItem = (item) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('Adding item', item);
    if (items.includes(item)) {
      console.log('Item is already added');
      return;
    }
    items.push(item);
    console.log('Items changed', items);
  }, 0);
};

const removeItem = (item) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('Removing item', item);
    const index = items.indexOf(item);
    if (index === -1) {
      console.log('Nothing to remove');
      return;
    }
    items.splice(index, 1);
    console.log('Items changed', items);
  }, 500);
};

// Because of race conditions, there is a case, when item adding
// from 1st and 2nd run of effect will happen before 'remove' call
// from 1st effect cleanup. And we'll happen to the situation where
// item is just deleted.
const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Run effect!');
    addItem(1);
    return () => {
      console.log('Run cleanup');
      removeItem(1);
    };
  }, []);

  return <div>see console</div>;
} 

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

The logic is needed:

1. When user enters the page, we should add item
2. When user leaves the page, we should remove item

To make the example more close to real word, I wrapped operations of add and remove into timeouts, so they look like requests. Requests can have different time, so we come to race conditions.

There are 2 issues:

1. In dev mode, React 18 runs effects twice on mount. This means we'll have this trace: effect 1 -> cleanup 1 -> effect 2. Because of requests nature, they can have different time to be executed. So we consider that remove request will take more time than add. Paying attention to the trace above, we'll have such sitation:
   Adding item (effect 1) -> Adding item again (effect 2, will be blocked since item is already added) -> removing item (clean up 1)

And the result will be empty array, that is not expected.

Trace above looks like this, because adding operations from effect 1 & 2 will take less time and will be executed firstly than removing operation from cleanup 1.

2. When changing lines in file, HMR will unmount and mount React components. It leads to the similar problem. Cleanup function will run first (unmount), then new effect (mount). Removal operation from cleanup will take more time, so we'll firstly add the user, and then we'll remove him. Again, empty array.

Comment: Please see [ask]. You need to show some code _here_.

Comment: @isherwood What do you mean? I've attached Stackblitz reproduction at the start of the message

Comment: See point #2 under `Help others reproduce the problem`.

Comment: 1. It's really the needed amount of code to reproduce the issue. It's not my production code, it's a simplified example.
2. I followed the best practise and attached link to the code with explanation of the issue.
3. I didn't attach any screenshots, etc.

So really can't understand what I've done wrong here

Answer (score 1):

You're right about React running `useEffect` twice in dev mode.
You can disable this feature if you remove `<React.StrictMode>`. It will have some other effects as well, you might want to [refer to the docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode)

Comment: It's a workaround and I think it shouldn't be solved like this